# setup proxy to gcp or aws k8s cluster in china

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

i like gks(google k8s engine) or acs (amazon container service), they are more user-friendly to me, actually to us, they are a little bit slow to access in china because of network issue, so is it possible to host a k8s cluster on gks or acs, and setup a proxy or load balancer on alicloud or something else, proxy requests to the cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, but very quickly China will block your site / Internet traffic unless you have applied for a license and been approved. I am an Alibaba Cloud MVP for both networking and security, so I know the pros and cons of working with the cloud in China.

When designing an architecture for the cloud, you need to think of China as a separate world and do not try to network China with the rest of the world. This means duplicating required infrastructure and services in China. If you have a website for the western world, you will need a separate website for China in a Chinese data center. You will use separate domain names, email servers and email addresses, etc.

Note that all of the above becomes more complex if you are accepting payments in China. The license requirements are more strict and compliance is mandatory.

Comment: so i just need to deploy k8s apps to gke and then how to setup proxy on alibaba cloud (create a load balancer) ?

Comment: Where are you running Kubernetes? If outside China and you are trying to access inside China, then reread my answer.

Comment: running in asia-northeast zone and trying to access inside China, can't get nginx proxy_pass work as expected